# Show that if $G \leq S_{n} $ has $r$ orbits when acting on $ \{ 1 , \dots , n \} $, then it is generated by at most $n - r $ elements.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-actions

The following is from exercise 1.5.14 of Permutation Group by Dixon and Mortimer and I'm not sure how to answer it.

Let $G \leq S_{n} $. Show that if $G$ has $r$ orbits when acting on $ \{ 1 , \dots , n \} $, then it is generated by at most $n - r $ elements.

Also, I noticed that there is a partial answer to the same question on the following link. [A problem of permutation group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498161/a-problem-of-permutation-group?rq=1)

At the end of the answer however it mentions that by looking at a stabiliser $G_{ \alpha} $ and then looking at the orbits of that stabiliser you can see that $G$ can be generated from the generators of $G _{ \alpha } $ as well as some other elements $G$ to give the required number of generators for $G$. It says that the other elements of $G$ that generate the group can be found by looking carefully at the orbits of $G$ and smaller orbits of $G_{ \alpha } $.

I am not sure how the orbits of $G _{\alpha } $ and $G$ show that we can find the correct number of generators.

Comment: Please put some effort into solving problems yourself. That's the only way to learn mathematics. This problem is not very difficult.

Comment: Hi, I agree with what you are saying that solving problems helps understand maths. However I have spent some time on this exercise and still have not reached the answer. I certainly don't just post questions on here just because I want a quick solution without doing the work. Unfortunately answers don't jump out to us so quickly every time. I'm sure every person reading this comment has been in a situation where they feel completely stuck, only to find the answer after and think it should have been obvious. I would like to move on through the book and I use this website as a last resort.

Comment: OK, as a hint use induction on $n-r$, starting with the base case $n-r=0$, when $G$ is trivial. For non-trivial $G$ apply induction to the stabilizer of a point $\alpha$ in an orbit of $G$ of size greater than $1$ (so this stabilizer has more orbits than $G$), and then adjoin generators until you generate all of $G$.